# Can someone explain mapping Restkit Get results mapping into an Array

Tags: restkit

I've been through the available documentation including https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping and I haven't been able to find an explanation or examples to map GET results in

- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray*)objects

What exactly is (NSArray*)objects ?

When I returned just one JSON object from the server I was able to map it with :

```
NSString *bodyResults;
bodyResults = [[objectLoader response] bodyAsString];

NSDictionary *resultsDictionary = [bodyResults objectFromJSONString];

NSString *subject = [resultsDictionary  objectForKey:@"subject"];
```

But now that i'm returning a JSON list (a selection of objects) I'm having trouble.

I'm mapped the object before submitting the get:

//map offering
    RKObjectMapping* offeringMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Offering class]];
    [offeringMapping mapKeyPath:@"categoryId" toAttribute:@"categoryId"];
    [offeringMapping mapKeyPath:@"merchantId" toAttribute:@"merchantId"];
    [offeringMapping mapKeyPath:@"name" toAttribute:@"name"];
    [offeringMapping mapKeyPath:@"latitude" toAttribute:@"latitude"];
    [offeringMapping mapKeyPath:@"longitude" toAttribute:@"longitude"];

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:offeringMapping forKeyPath:@"offering"];

double latitude = [(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] currentLatitude];
double longitude = [(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] currentLongitude];


NSString *latitudeString = [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:latitude] stringValue];
NSString *longitudeString = [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:longitude] stringValue];

NSDictionary *getParams = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithKeysAndObjects:
                            @"lat",latitudeString,
                            @"long",longitudeString,
                            nil];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:[@"/merchantofferings" stringByAppendingQueryParameters:getParams] delegate:self];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In response to your first question, (NSArray *)objects is an array of the objects that were loaded by the objectLoader.  So in your case, they should be objects of type Offering populated with the attributes that you mapped in the object mapping.

Do you have a sample of the JSON that you're returning from the GET request that you can post here?  Are you sure that it's valid JSON and is being returned exactly as you anticipate?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm finding that there is nothing in that NSArray. (As was the case earlier when I was just returning one object. Here's my code:

Comment: - (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray*)objects {

    NSEnumerator *e = [objects objectEnumerator];
    Offering* object;
    while (object = [e nextObject]) {
        NSString *name = object.name;

        NSString *catName = object.categoryName;
    
        NSString *desc = object.description;
    }

Comment: the JSON as shown in the console is: RKObjectLoader.m:193 bodyAsString: [{"categoryId":"try it"},{"facetListValues":"ok"}]

Comment: In the console it shows: KObjectMapper.m:81 Adding mapping error: Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: '' but I am doing a setMapping:offeringMapping with consistent attributes.

Comment: By the way it's now not going to the didLoadObjects routine but to the error routine ... not sure why it went to didLoadObjects earlier.